# How can I provide a padding to the text inside a Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have a scenario with two Sign-in Buttons like below:

[image]

You can clearly see the misalignment of the texts in the two Buttons. Now, I am aware that there is gravity manipulation available for Button's content but in the present case, gravity cannot be made to apply for a custom positioning/padding.

So, my question is, is there any way to position this text inside a standard Android `Button`?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: just try one time set  drawable padding

Comment: Add a transparent image (or a drawable) to the second Button, with the same size of the image on the upper one,

Comment: Put a dummy `View` with transparent color and equivalent dimensions of that Google logo as in the blue button.

Comment: Can anybody tell me, why the dowvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to bottom one, like:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

where `10dp` should match upper's image width, but while that would make labels aligned, the button itself would look bad, with label non-centered, so the only solution that would make it all look correct is to add image to bottom button as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this **Add a transparent  a drawable to your Button, with the same size of the image on the 1st Button like this**

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
   android:text="Sign Up with Email" />
```

create a transparent  a drawable in  `res/drawable` like this

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#00000"  // add here transparent color
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
```